# Update uilabel from blocks

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Importing multiple photos from album, one of the delegate method is

```
// Here info is array of dictionary containing FileName/AssetURL etc
- (void)somePicker(SomePicker*)somePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info {
    _importStatusView.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:_importStatusView];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSNumber *total = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:info.count];
        [info enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSDictionary *imageInfo = (NSDictionary*)obj;
            NSString *fileName = [imageInfo objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerFileName"];
            NSURL *imageURL = [imageInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
            ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            [assetLibrary assetForURL:imageURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                NSLog(@"start");
                ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
                NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
                NSString *filePath = [_currentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
                [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

                //This also has no effect 
                //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //_lblImportCountStatus.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of %d",idx+1,[total integerValue]];
                    //NSLog(@"Label value->%@",_lblImportCountStatus.text); //This prints values but after everything is finished it prints all line at once i.e. at the end of the enumeration of all items 
                //});

            //Update UI
            NSNumber *current = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:idx+1];
            NSDictionary *status = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:current,@"current", total,@"totalCount", nil];
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateImportCount:) withObject:status waitUntilDone:YES];

                //_lblImportCountStatus.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of %d",idx+1,[total integerValue]];
                if(idx==info.count-1){
                    [_importStatusView removeFromSuperview];
                }

                NSLog(@"Finish");
            } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
            }];
        }];
    }];
}
```

My declaration for status view and label is

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *importStatusView; //View containing label 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblImportCountStatus; //Label
```

Everything in above code is working fine and as expected, but the problem is a importStatusView is being added to the screen but lblImportCountStatus value is not displaying, though If I log the values it shows updated.

When enumeration is finished at the end all the NSLog gets printed for e.g. If I have imported 10 photos than at last it prints, i.e. dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() this function has no effect at all while enumeration is in progress.

```
Label value->1 of 10
Label value->2 of 10
Label value->3 of 10
Label value->4 of 10
Label value->5 of 10
Label value->6 of 10
Label value->7 of 10
Label value->8 of 10
Label value->9 of 10
Label value->10 of 10
```

What could be the issue ?

Update:

```
-(void)updateImportCount:(NSDictionary*)info{ //(NSNumber*)current forTotalItems:(NSNumber*)totalCount{
    NSNumber *current = [info objectForKey:@"current"];
    NSNumber *totalCount = [info objectForKey:@"totalCount"];
    _lblImportCountStatus.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of %d",[current integerValue],[totalCount integerValue]];
    [_lblImportCountStatus setNeedsDisplay];
    NSLog(@"Updating ui->%@",_lblImportCountStatus.text);
}
```

Above function works on main thread and updates but stil label is not shown it prints following NSLog

```
start
Updating ui->1 of 10
Finish
start
Updating ui->2 of 10
Finish
start
Updating ui->3 of 10
Finish
start
Updating ui->4 of 10
Finish
start
Updating ui->5 of 10
Finish
start
Updating ui->6 of 10
Finish
start
Updating ui->7 of 10
Finish
start
Updating ui->8 of 10
Finish
start
Updating ui->9 of 10
Finish
start
Updating ui->10 of 10
Finish
```

I have uploaded project at [this location](https://github.com/Janak-Nirmal/ImportImageProblem), please feel free to help.

Comment: Are you sure that label is connected right, check for nil?

Comment: Probably pickerview is dismissed and released from memory before it updates the UI.

Comment: @DmitryShevchenko if I nslog labels value it prints 1 of n, 2 of n and so on

Comment: @whitewolf09 AFAIK pickerview has nothing to do with UI updates can you be some more specific ?

Comment: @DmitryShevchenko updated code which prints nslog correctly but still label is not shown.

Comment: did u updating your Label UI in background thread, please check. You cannot update ur UI in background thread, u need to move main thread to updated the UI.

Comment: @SatishAzad check my updated code `updateImportCount` function is called on the main thread and it updates the only thing is a label is not visible on screen.

Comment: i m not sure why this is happening,because there is no problem in ur code for updating. Just want to know whats is frame size of lblImportCountStatus and font size.>?

Comment: @SatishAzad frame is {{40,29},{100,21}}, yes its the problem I can't find out so seeking help from GURUs :).

Comment: so the problem is here, u can now resolve it easily. also mark the comment so it also helps to other. :)

Comment: I can see that you are setting `_lblImportCountStatus.text = [NSString stringWithFor...` the line after your are sending update message on main thread too, is that your intention or you forgot to comment out that line of code?

Comment: @SatishAzad may be you misunderstood, but the frame is not the problem. What I wanted to say is I can't find out the problem. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @M.Porooshani forgot to comment out. Thank you for pointing that, now corrected.

Comment: your problem still exists?

Comment: @M.Porooshani yes its not yet resolved.

Comment: is `_lblImportCountStatus` a child of `importStatusView`? and if so, have you tried this in your update method: `[self.importStatusView layoutIfNeeded];` ?

Comment: @M.Porooshani I have tried that but still no luck.

Comment: Did you double-check in Interface Builder that your `UILabel` is not set to "Hidden", or some other thing like this (hidden behind another UI component, white font on white background, etc.)?

Comment: @Romain yes, I have cross checked all the possibilities, infect I have checked setting red color now after your comment.

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint where you are updating the `UILabel`'s text? Is `_lblImportCountStatus` actually set to something (not `nil`) and if yes, what are its `text` property values before and after your code to update it?

Comment: @Romain yes it is non nil and values are also updated. This is something related to the thread I believe now so looking for other options but yet not luck.

Comment: have you tried sending `_lblImportCountStatus` to front? maybe it gets under some views and therefore not visible! try replacing `_lblImportCountStatus` with an arbitrary placed `UIlabel` with another name and see what's going on!

Comment: Can you comment out these lines: `if(idx==info.count-1){ [_importStatusView removeFromSuperview]; }`, or at least put them in a main thread call like the `UILabel` update?

Comment: @Romain I have uploaded [code](https://github.com/Janak-Nirmal/ImportImageProblem)

Comment: possibly the fast enumeration is not giving the main runloop time to update.

Comment: @Janak: I'll take a look at it tonight if nobody finds out before...

Comment: @Romain Thanks a lot in advance, mean while I am also trying and will update if find any solution - looking for nsoperation stuff.

Comment: @JanakNirmal I checked your code, couldn't find the allocation and frame setting of UILabel. Could you please help me with?

Comment: @PiyushDubey IBOutlet is set so no need to allocation as everything is in XIB.

Comment: @JanakNirmal Oh..!! My mistake. I didn't check the XIB.

Comment: @JanakNirmal that your sample project getting creashed plz fix it and reupload for checking

Comment: @NitinGohel I have updated the code and working now. Sorry about previous code.

Comment: Spent half an hour with your Xcode project but I must admit I didn't find a working solution. It might have to do with the fact that you're iterating in blocks, within another block, but since you're dispatching UI updates to the main thread, it *should* work. You shouldn't even need to call things like `setNeedsDisplay`, since `setText:` already does this behind the scene... Unless a new idea comes during the night, I'm giving up on this one! Good luck!

Comment: @Romain Thanks for putting all your hard work, still I have also not found any solution and looking out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All those blocks *are* executing on the main thread (the easiest way to verify this is using `NSThread`'s `+currentThread` to get the current thread, and `-isMainThread` to check if it's the main thread. Anywhere you have code that you want to see what thread it's on, do something like this:

```
NSLog( @"enumeration block on main thread: %@", 
       [[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread] ? @"YES" : @"NO" );
```

I think the problem is, since this is all executing on the main thread, you're locking up the runloop, not giving the UI a chance to update.

The **right** way to fix this is probably to really do this processing on a separate thread (calling the code to update the UI via `performSelectorOnMainThread:`, as you're doing now). But, a quick hack to make it work would be to allow the runloop to run. At the end of `updateImportCount:`, do something like this:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate date]];
```

It ain't pretty, but it will work.

**Update:**
In Cocoa (Mac OS and iOS) there a concept of a runloop. The main thread of your application drives an NSRunLoop which serves as the event loop. User actions -- taps, etc. -- are processed through this loop, as are things like timers, network connections, and other things. See the [NSRunLoop Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information on that.

In iOS, drawing also happens on the runloop. So when you call `setNeedsDisplay` on a view, that view is not redrawn immediately. Rather, it's simply flagged as needing redraw, and then on the next drawing cycle (the next trip through the runloop) the actual drawing takes place. The [UIView reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html) has a brief description of this (see the section "The View Drawing Cycle".  Quoting from that section:

> When the actual content of your view changes, it is your
>   responsibility to notify the system that your view needs to be
>   redrawn. You do this by calling your view’s setNeedsDisplay or
>   setNeedsDisplayInRect: method of the view. These methods let the
>   system know that it should update the view during the next drawing
>   cycle. Because it waits until the next drawing cycle to update the
>   view, you can call these methods on multiple views to update them at
>   the same time.

When you return from whatever method was called in response to some user action (in this case, `somePicker:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`, control returns to the runloop, and any views that need redrawing, are. However, if you do a bunch of processing on the main thread without returning, the runloop is basically stalled, and drawing won't take place. The code above basically gives the runloop some time to process, so drawing can take place. `[NSDate date]` returns the current date and time, right now, so that basically tells the runlooop "run until right now", which ends up giving it one cycle through the loop, giving you one drawing cycle, which is an opportunity for your label to be redrawn.

Comment: This works, I have currently tested on the simulator. Can you please elaborate what it does actually ? why it works ?